# I am not able to change the directory

Tags: command-prompt

Whenever i use cd to move from C to D, the directory is changed to D but it again becomes C.
I want to make D as my directory.

C:\me>cd D:
D:\

C:\me>

Answer (score 1):

cd stands for change directory

```
C:\me>D:
```

and 'enter' will change your drive